# XSLT, need to insert javascript into onclick handler

Tags: javascript, xslt

Been trying this a bunch of different ways. Below (doesn't work) is basically what I want to do. Define the "onclick" code with the variable "defineClick", and insert it into the div/onclick handler, dynamically. The $block variable is defined elsewere in the file. thanks

```
          <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="txtBlockTarget='_blank'">
                    <xsl:variable name="defineClick">window.open('{$block}','_blank');</xsl:variable>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:variable name="defineClick">location.href='{$block}';</xsl:variable>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>


            <div onclick="{$defineClick}" style="cursor: pointer;">

            .....more xsl.....

            </div>
```

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?

Answer (score 0):

A variable defined within `xsl:when` is scoped to its parent and will not be available outside of it.

Try reversing the order of your operations to something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="defineClick">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="txtBlockTarget='_blank'">window.open('{$block}','_blank');</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>location.href='{$block}';</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<div onclick="{$defineClick}" style="cursor: pointer;">
    ....more xsl.....
</div>
```

---

**Note**: I am not sure what you intend when you write `{$block}` withing your variable; as it stands, it is no more than a meaningless string. But that would be a subject for a separate question.

Comment: Its a variable that works elsewhere in the code, I just don't know how to get it to load the value when embedded in the javascript. Is there a way to "escape" it?

Thanks for the fix about reversing the order, I can get the "defineClick" var now.

Comment: Try using `<xsl:value-of select="$block" />` to insert the variable's content. Hard to be more specific without seeing the entire picture. If you still cannot get it to work, post a new question (and close this one if it's answered).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michael! Sometimes the answer is so much simpler than it seems (and the agony of getting there). Code below works.

```
<xsl:variable name="defineClick">
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="txtBlockTarget='_blank'">window.open('<xsl:value-of select="$block" />');</xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>location.href='<xsl:value-of select="$block" />'</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<div onclick="{$defineClick}" style="cursor: pointer;">
......
```